# IdentityServer 4 - idsrv and idsrv.session cookies blocked on signin-oidc call

Tags: cookies, openid-connect, identityserver4, saml-2.0

I'm working with IDS4 behind a reverse proxy.  I find these IdentityServer cookies blocked on the signin-oidc call:

Blocked Cookies
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/zimtm.png)

The error msg on the cookies is:

"The cookie was blocked because it's path was not an exact match for a super directory or the request URL's path."

I've searched quite a bit but only find dead ends, any help would be much appreciated.  I am able to authenticate but I feel like there is something I'm just not understanding here.

Comment: Your cookies have a `path=/` component set - you need to remove it because you shouldn't have a path set on IdentityServer's cookies because IdentityServer assumes it has total ownership of the path-space of the HTTP _authority_ it's being accesssed from (i.e. IdentityServer should not share an IIS website with any other Application Scopes).

Comment: Also, why did you tag your question with `saml-2.0`? IdentityServer doesn't support SAML, it's strictly OAuth2+OIDC-only.

Comment: I added saml because I'm using ComponentSpace and this supports saml 2.0 with IDS.  Perhaps I lack comprehension here but I'm not setting a path value on any of my cookies.

Comment: Are you able to run and debug your IS set-up locally? If so, do that and start a new session and try to find out where those nonempty `/....` path values (that you covered up in your screenshot) are coming from.

Comment: Yes, I can debug with IIS locally.  I'm having a rough time finding where that path value is coming from as those cookies are generated by IDS.  The path on those cookies points to the IDS implementation so I would think it's a configuration issue but I just can't find it, or a way to override it.  I fear I'm overlooking something obvious but I just can't see what it is.

Comment: Oh, right - yes, for some reason _all_ of the `Endpoint` (action handlers) in IS4 are marked as `internal` classes and they're difficult to patch-out in production - but that won't be necessary (but not being able to easily step-through their code sucks, yes).  Can you please show an un-censored version of your sookies screenshot? We really need to find out what that `path=/` value is so we know where it's coming from.

Comment: ...but I _speculate_ that you have done something like accidentally assigned a path string to the wrong property in IS' `ConfigureInternalCookieOptions`, for example, maybe you have `options.CookiePath = "/login"` when it should be `options.LoginPath = "/login"`? See here for reference: https://github.com/DuendeSoftware/IdentityServer/blob/aff8930ebdcbcb3e2a4c8713a3fdf88712c757de/src/IdentityServer/Configuration/DependencyInjection/ConfigureInternalCookieOptions.cs#L14